# Display agents API ADO with SystemCapabilities filter

Tags: azure, api, azure-devops

how can I display the ADO agents using the ADO API, but so as to filter out the agents that in System Capabilities have e.g. key=value

i tried:

https://dev.azure.com/org/_apis/distributedtask/pools/111/agents?capabilities=key=value&api-version=5.1

https://dev.azure.com/org/_apis/distributedtask/pools/111/agents/?key=valueA&api-version=5.1

https://dev.azure.com/org/_apis/distributedtask/pools/111/agents?demands=SystemCapabilities.key=value&api-version=5.1

It shows me all agents in pool 111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use demands: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#manually-entered-demands

> ```
> pool:
>   name: MyPool
>   demands:
>   - myCustomCapability   # exists check for myCustomCapability
>   - Agent.Version -equals 2.144.0 # equals check for Agent.Version 2.144.0
> ```

as a template:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/agents?includeCapabilities=true&demands=your_capability -equals value
```

as an example:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/agents?includeCapabilities=true&demands=Agent.Version%20-equals%202.213.2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works, but i have one question. 

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/@{parameters('subsription_id')}/resourceGroups/@{parameters('resource_group_name')}/providers/Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/@{parameters('devtestlab_name') }/virtualmachines/namevm/start?api-version=

Without specifying vmname, and using only demands

Comment: @sphtd97 as I understand.. this is something about azure VMs... please, rise another question to discuss that.